# Problem creating app with py2app: misssing rubicon

Tags: python, macos, type-conversion, setup.py, py2app

I'm trying to create an app from my python script on mac. Every time I've tried to create it by running $ python setup.py py2app in terminal I get an error " ImportError: No module named 'rubicon' ". I know that rubicon is installed.

I've been trying to find a solution for a while. If it helps, here is my setup file (I made sure that all modules being imported are already installed through pip).

```
`setup.py:

import os
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'iconfile': 'icons8-automation-64.png'
}

# Get the path to the data_folder relative to the setup.py script
data_folder_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'data_folder')

# List of data files to include in the app bundle
DATA_FILES = [
    ('data_folder', [os.path.join(data_folder_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(data_folder_path)])
]

setup(
    name='AchToCRM',
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,  # Include the data_folder in the app bundle
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    install_requires=[
        'selenium',
        'pandas',
        'openpyxl',
        'pyautogui'
    ]
)`
```

This is my first post to stack overflow so thank you for bearing with me.

I have uninstalled it and reinstalled rubicon multiple times, I've also confirmed that rubicon exists in the venv folder.
When I run pip show rubicon-objc in terminal it shows
Name: rubicon-objc
Version: 0.4.6

Answer (score 0):

If your application does not use this module or modules that are used in it do not depend on the rubicon, then try add the option **'excludes': ['rubicon']** to the options in your setup.py file.
To specify py2app to ignore the rubicon module assembly of the application.

```
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'iconfile': 'icons8-automation-64.png'
},
    'excludes': ['rubicon'],
```